Does 25% Spanish mean grandparent was born in Spain?
I took a DNA test through Ancestry; it shows I'm 44% Indigenous America's Mexico and 25% Spanish. These are the main percentages, there are many others! I'm wondering about the Spanish component.
Does this mean a grandparent was born in Spain?

No.
Imagine a married couple, who are both 100% Spanish.
They have a child - and that's one of your grandparents.
No matter where the child was born, your genetic makeup would be the same.
In Spain? Ok.  In Portugal? The same.
In Australia? Still the same.
In Antartica?  Still the same.

@Marshall Clow nailed the answer regarding your question if your 25% Spanish means that your ancestor was born in Spain.
I'd like to address the idea that 25% means a grandfather. You are a mixture of your ancestors. If humanity had started 100 years ago (like a lot of people probably think it did, considering how little history they know), then yes that would most likely mean that your 25% came from a single grandfather.
Imagine those 25% you have, where you got 12.5% from your paternal side and another 12.5% from your maternal side. Your dad would originally have 25% and your mother another 25% and that would go neatly into you as half of what they have. So that maybe means that you have two great-grandparents born in Spain. However, note that what applies to you also applies to your parents, so maybe 4 of your 2x-great-grandparents were born in Spain.
And even worse, these percentages change ALL THE TIME. So maybe in 1 year, your DNA company refreshes their algorithm and suddenly you're no longer 25% Spanish, but instead you're only 15%.
You can help to figure this out by the following:

Do your paper research. Figure out who your ancestors were, and you'll know their origin story.

Test your parents. If your father is 50% Spanish, the chances that your hypotheses is correct grows a lot. If you can't test your parents, then test your aunts/uncles. I'd suggest to test your aunts/uncles regardless. Or even better: test your grandparents or grand-uncles.


